# Is there any built-in/simple way to let a string do not be transferred?

Tags: javascript

In Python, if we add `r` before a string:

```
str = r"text\n abc"
print (str)  # asdas\n asdas  ]
```

The str will not be transferred.

how about in JavaScript? is there any simple way to achieve? 
I only know

```
var str = "text\\n abc"
```

but is there any simple/built-in way to do like Python?

Comment: What is the end goal? Why are you trying to prevent transferring?

Comment: `str.replace(/\n/g, '')` - I'd approach it this way if it's just about the `\n` characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to Pythons `r` is [String.raw()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw)

```
var str = String.raw`text\n abc`;
```